# print multicolumn formatted text vb6

Tags: printing, vb6, formatting

i need to print formatted text like in the image below, how can i achive this in vb6, given that vb6 print object is not friendly for such this

The data i need to print that represented by the boxes are non related

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very difficult. You use the **ScaleLeft**, **ScaleWidth**, **CurrentX**, and **CurrentY** properties to set where printing begins on the page. In this case you will probably also want to set the **Orientation** property to **vbPROPortrait**. Using those positioning properties, and setting the font and style you want you then call **Printer.Print**

This method will draw 4 boxes onto a page. Play with the (x, y) coordinates or hard code the numbers to alter the sizes. Remove the .EndDoc statement if you don't want the printer to print the page from this method and call Printer.EndDoc from somewhere else. Full Printer object documentation for VB6 can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443915%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

```
Private Sub DrawBox()

    With Printer
        .ScaleMode = vbTwips
        lngScaleWidth = .ScaleWidth
        lngScaleHeight = .ScaleHeight
        Printer.Line (.ScaleLeft + lngMargin, .ScaleTop + lngMargin)-(lngScaleWidth / 2 - (100 + lngMargin * 2), lngScaleHeight / 2 - (100 + lngMargin * 2)), lngColor, B
        Printer.Line (lngScaleWidth / 2 + (100 + lngMargin * 2), .ScaleTop + lngMargin)-(.ScaleWidth - lngMargin, lngScaleHeight / 2 - (100 + lngMargin * 2)), lngColor, B
        Printer.Line (.ScaleLeft + lngMargin, lngScaleHeight / 2 + (100 + lngMargin * 2))-(lngScaleWidth / 2 - (100 + lngMargin * 2), .ScaleHeight - lngMargin), lngColor, B
        Printer.Line (lngScaleWidth / 2 + (100 + lngMargin * 2), lngScaleHeight / 2 + (100 + lngMargin * 2))-(.ScaleWidth - lngMargin, .ScaleHeight - lngMargin), lngColor, B
        .EndDoc
    End With

End Sub
```

The sample code below demonstrates some of the positioning and other properties.

```
Dim lMargin as Integer
lMargin = 200

With Printer
    .FontBold = True
    .FontItalic = False
    .CurrentY = .CurrentY + (3 * .TextHeight(App.ProductName))
    .CurrentX = lLeftMargin
    .FontName = "Arial"
    .FontSize = 11
    Printer.Print "Date " & strTransDate
End With
```

Comment: +1 Also sounds like Smith will need to do text-justification. There are methods on  the `Printer` object that return the length that will be occupied by a piece of text in twips.

Comment: some questions. 1. how to i know that i have reached the end of the page in col1, so i can move to col2? 2. how do i formatting like "**Bold:** Text" as i print, and 3. how do i draw a rectangle, color it and write text on it?

Comment: @Smith I didn't list all of the properties available because I though they were implied. For instance ScaleWidth implies there is also a ScaleHeight. The above example demonstrates the FontBold, FontItalic, FontName, and FontSize properties, and there are others you can discover by using the Intellisense feature of the dev environment. THe "With" statement above allows the coding shorthand of the .PropertyName syntax. For instance without using the With statement the code would be Printer.FontBold = True.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but you did not tell me how to do the multi column

Comment: @Smith I told you the properties you use to control where on the page you print, and the properties you use to measure the string being printed. **CurrentX**, **CurrentY** to get and set location, **TextHeight**, **TextWidth** to measure your printed string.

Comment: can you provide any reference or doc for this?